# Sending binary file over TCP from Python server to Java client

Tags: java, python, image, tcp

I am trying to send binary files over TCP. The server is written in Python and the client in Java.

**Server:**

```
import socket;

TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
TCP_PORT = 5001;

BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;

try:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
    s.listen(1)
except:
    "Can not bind server on port: "+ str(TCP_PORT) +"\n";

while 1:
    print("Wait for connections!!!\n");
    conn, addr = s.accept();
    print("Receive a new connection!!!\n");

# presentation of client
data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE);
if not data:
    conn.close();
    print("Lost connection!!!");
    continue;

# respond to client
conn.sendall("Hello 1\n");

# receive new request
data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE);
if not data:
    continue;

conn.sendall("OK\n");

f = open('testImage.jpg', "rb");
dataRaw = f.read();
f.close();

fileSize = len(dataRaw); #sys.getsizeof(dataRaw);

# send file size
conn.send(str(fileSize) + "\n");

conn.send(dataRaw);

conn.sendall("OK\n");
```

**Client**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

public class mainTestReceiveFile
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        String usr2ConnectDefault = "127.0.0.1";
        int port2ConnectDefault = 5001;
        Socket socket;
        BufferedReader in;
        PrintWriter out;

        socket = new Socket(usr2ConnectDefault, port2ConnectDefault);
        System.out.println("Connected to server...sending echo string");

        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true);

        // say hello to server
        out.println("Hello");
        // read hello from server
        String readString = in.readLine();
        System.out.println(readString);

        out.println("ReadFile");

        // verify if request is OK
        readString = in.readLine();
        if(readString.compareToIgnoreCase("OK") == 0)
            System.out.println("Receive new file!!!");
        else
        {
            socket.close();
            return;
        }

        // get size of file
        readString = in.readLine();
        int sizeOfFile = Integer.parseInt(readString);
        //InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
        byte[] fileData = new byte[sizeOfFile];

        for(int i = 0; i < sizeOfFile; i++)
        {
            fileData[i] = (byte)in.read();
        }

        // save file to disk
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("fileImage.jpg");
        try
        {
            fos.write(fileData);
        }
        finally {
            fos.close();
        }

        // verify if request is OK
        readString = in.readLine();
        if(readString.compareToIgnoreCase("OK") == 0)
            System.out.println("New file received!!!");
        else
        {
            socket.close();
            return;
        }

        socket.close();
    }
}
```

I am trying to send for example one image. In the client side, the image received has the same size (file size and number of pixels) but the data is corrupted.

Comment: Your code is broken. There are some unexpected `continue` in the server python source file.

Comment: `BufferedReader` is supposed to read... text. By sending an image, you ask it to read some binary data. For binary data, use `BufferedInputStream`

Comment: I am trying to use BufferedInputStream to read bin and BufferedReader to read char because I would like to continue to read as test.
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
BufferedInputStream inBin = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
The client side block when is trying to read OK in line readString = in.readLine(); What I need to do?
The image is correctly received.